# jQuery - Move element with children triggered by window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I have a filter on my website positioned in an aside with a class 'left-bar'. My site is responsive and i want the filter to move to the div with the class 'mobile-top-bar'.

With the first 'if' i check if the window isn't already below 992px and when that's the case the filter will be moved to the 'mobile-top-bar' (this works great)

```
if ($(window).width() < 992) {
    $('#moveableFilter').prependTo('.mobile-top-bar');
}
```

With the second piece of code i've made a function that should move the filter back and forth, but that doesn't happen. The filter already disappears from the 'left-bar' when i slightly change the width of the window (when it's still above 992px) and when i change it below 992px it isn't present in the mobile-top-bar.

What did i do wrong?

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var win = $(this);
  if (win.width() < 992) {
      $('#moveableFilter').prependTo('.left-bar');
  } else if (win.width() >= 992) {
      $('#moveableFilter').prependTo('.mobile-top-bar');
  }
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, any reason you're not using [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: and use both filters with 'display:none/block;'? because the filters generated in the #moveableFilter have same id's. The first filter of both 'left-bar' and 'mobile-top-bar' would have the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you switched the cases around by accident. Try this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var win = $(this);
  if (win.width() >= 992) {
      $('#moveableFilter').prependTo('.left-bar');
  } else if (win.width() < 992) {
      $('#moveableFilter').prependTo('.mobile-top-bar');
  }
});
```

... However, I do agree with the comment that says that it would be better not to use two different bars, but to move it with CSS media queries.

Comment: How can i move the div with its children using media queries?

Comment: Here's how to use media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries. Inside the media query for max-width:992px, you'd position the .left-bar Div the same way the .mobile-top-bar is positioned now. If my answer solved your problem, please accept!

Comment: The jQuery code works fine! Thanks! I indeed switched it by accident.

Comment: Since the filter is a part (of many parts) of the left-bar and a part (of many) of the mobile-top-bar, it is a little bit more complicated.